# Finder: unlock files grid in folders

Tags: finder

Using Finder:

In some folders, I can move the files around. Place them where I want in that folder. This is very good for the eyes, when the folder holds many files and only a handfuld om them are important/relevant

In other folders I simply cannot. The files are somehow fixed to a grid and can't be moved

Changing the "sort by" to NOTHING does not help, still fixed

**How do I force Finder to let me place the files as I choose?**

*Macbook Pro 2012 with Yosemite 10.10.1*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In one of the folders where the items are "stuck", go to View menu > Show View Options, or press <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>J</kbd>.

In the new window, change "Arrange By" to "None" and "Sort By" to "None".

Comment: Ah. Didn't know there were 2 (arrange and sort). Working fine now, thanks ;)